# How to set script-src in a Chrome packaged app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create a Chrome packaged app from a complicated web app.  I'm currently getting the error:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
>   chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly
>   set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

How do I explicitly set the policy in my manifest.json?  I've tried things like:

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'inline'; script-src 'inline'"
```

but I still get the same error message.  Is my syntax wrong, or is the error a red herring?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't loosen the default CSP in a packaged app. If you're doing something like `<button id="foo" onclick="doSomething()">` then you should instead include a separate JS file in the HTML where you do a `document.querySelector("#foo").onclick = doSomething;` in your onload handler. This will comply with CSP and make your app more resistant to XSS attacks.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I wish they'd just say that rather than implying I could explicitly set a different option.

Comment: A fair point. I think what's happening is that the warning is being triggered for the *default* CSP, so that we (Chromium developers) need to update it in the source code. From your perspective, as the developer, the warning is an itch you can't scratch. I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks.  I also seem to get the message even if I try explicitly setting a security policy.

Comment: @sowbug, Is this the only way? Shouldn't there be some setting we can use to enable inline scripts?

Comment: No. It was an early component of the design of the security model for Chrome Apps. It's an inconvenience if you're importing third-party scripts that weren't built with the security risks of inline scripts in mind. But the tradeoff is getting Chrome Apps' advanced capabilities that aren't available on the open web (yet).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and I while reading [this document](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#include_sandbox) I found the following:

```
"sandbox": {
    "pages": ["sandboxed.html"]
}
```